# Finding Laurent series of the following function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How does one find the Laurent Series expansion of $f(z) = \frac{-1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ in the annulus $\{ z  \text{ such that } 1<|z|<2 \}$?

Comment: Can you find the Laurent series expansions of $\frac{1}{z-1}$ and $\frac{1}{z-2}$ in the given annulus?

Comment: not really. can you help?

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$\frac{-1}{(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z-2}.$$

Note that, if $|1/z|<1$, that is, if $|z|>1$:
$$\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-(1/z)}=\frac{1}{z}(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2}+\dots)=z^{-1}+z^{-2}+\dots$$

and, if $|z|<2$:
$$-\frac{1}{z-2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-(z/2)}=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{4}+\frac{z^3}{8}+\dots)$$

In the annulus, both series converges, so you can sum them.